# Git is ignoring specific directory, not on ignore or exclude list

Tags: git

So I decided to add the source code of a library into one my repositories. The source is in a repository itself and I originally just added the full repository. Git ignored all content and only added the folder itself. Now no matter what I do it keeps ignoring the content of a folder by that name. I have tried deleting the folder in one commit and re-adding in the next with just a single txt file in it, still ignores any content.

I have cleared the .gitignore and there is also nothing in .git/info/exclude either. Is there a third place where ignore paths may be placed?

Comment: there is no other git ignore files deeper in your tree?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel stupid now. I misinterpreted the output of git status. It doesn't show untracked files in the untracked folder before adding, it only shows the untracked folder. So I mistakenly assumed it meant git add . would have the same effect. After using git add . the untracked files were added -.-